# I want the link generated, copied to clipboard

Tags: copy

```
<div class="form-group m-l-4">
            <label class="" for="">Share It :</label>
            <p id="postcodep<?php echo isset($campaign['post_id']) ? $campaign['post_id'] : 0 ?>" style="    word-wrap: break-word;     margin: 0px;
               border: 1px solid #1083d4;
               padding: 5px;
               }">Please Generate Link</p>
        </div>
        <!--<button ng-click="getCode('<?php echo isset($campaign['post_id']) ? $campaign['post_id'] : 0 ?>', <?php echo isset($campaign['campaign_id']) ? $campaign['campaign_id'] : 0 ?>)" class="btn btn-default m-l-2   waves-effect waves-light"><span class="fa "></span>GET</button>-->

        <button ng-click="getCode('<?php echo isset($campaign['post_id']) ? $campaign['post_id'] : 0 ?>', <?php echo isset($campaign['campaign_id']) ? $campaign['campaign_id'] : 0 ?>)" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light m-b-5 btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-plus " ></span> GENERATE LINK </button>
```

I want the link generated, copied to clipboard
as  soon as people click on generate link.      Can anyone help me I am not to familiar with angular?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this is working in Angular, but in pure JavaScript it can be something like:

```
<button id="get-link" data-link="<?= getCode() ?>">GET LINK</button>
```

---

```
document.getElementById('get-link').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var temp = document.createElement('textarea');
    temp.value = this.getAttribute('data-link');

    document.body.appendChild(temp);
    temp.select();

    document.execCommand('copy');

    document.body.removeChild(temp);    
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply         this portion of code data-link="<?= getCode() ?>" 
     does not allow the page to load normal    I am only getting a text box   nothing else .